# DolphinDB: The difference between sqlCol and sqlColAlias

Tags: error-handling, metaprogramming, dolphindb

Here is my script, where `sqlCol` and `sqlColAlias` are used respectively:

```
code=`000905
sql((sqlCol(`date),sqlCol(code,ratios, `ret)),table ).eval()
sql((sqlCol(`date),sqlColAlias(<ratios(code)>,`ret)),table).eval()
```

`` sqlCol(code,ratios,`ret) ``

and

`` sqlColAlias(<ratios(code)>,`ret) ``

are expected to achieve the same result. But the latter one raises the following error:

`Server response: '::evaluate(sql((sqlCol("date"), sqlColAlias(< ratios(code) >, "ret")), table)) => Usage: ratios(X). X can't be string or symbol type.'`

Why is that happening? What is the difference between these two functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sql((sqlCol(`date),sqlCol(code,ratios, `ret)),table ).eval()
```

In `` sqlCol(code,ratios,`ret) ``, `code` is a column variable representing the column `00905` in the table. Therefore, the expression calculates the ratios of the column `00905`.

```
sql((sqlCol(`date),sqlColAlias(<ratios(code)>,`ret)),table).eval()
```

In `` sqlColAlias(<ratios(code)>,`ret) ``, `<ratios(code)>` is a metacode expression. `code`, instead of being a variable used to query the column `00905`, is parsed into a new column containing entirely the string `"code"`, which cannot be used as the parameter of `ratios()`.